# response.write() not working in exec

Tags: node.js

I am following a node.js tutorial and am making a simple server that will display contents of a directory.

```
function start(response) {
  console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");

  // if I put response.write("blah") here it works
  console.log(response);
  exec("ls -lah", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(response);
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write(stdout);
    response.write("asdfasdf");

    console.log("asdf");
    console.log(stdout);
    response.end();
  });
}
```

This prints nothing on the browser, but shows up on the console.

I tried putting response.write() outside of the exec callback function, and it shows up perfectly on the browser.

Firefox is reporting that the request is not being set at all, not even the content-type header is being set. If I move that outside the exec callback function, it does get set.

Comment: To what function do you pass the start callback? node.js HTTP handlers usually get request as the first argument and response as the second.

Comment: It is coming from function onRequest(request, response)

Comment: Make sure that onRequest() does not call response.end() after invoking start(response), such error would cause the behavior that you are observing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure it doesn't get called somewhere. However, I do notice that if I put a response.write() RIGHT before the exec("ls -lah"...) line it still works.

Comment: Ah just noticed that indeed you were right. There's a response.end() call after invoking start(). Which makes sense why putting the response.write() before exec would work. If you'd like, make your resposne into an answer and I'll accept it